# Is surface always locally connected area in Euclidean 3d?

Tags: geometry, general-topology

I have some geometry in 3d (like road surface or terrain surface) and there could be several not connected parts of a road. 
So I'd like to know if I may unite these two not connected pieces of road in a term "surface".

And if I couldn't, then what is the best mathematical term for this?

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you have two currently separate surfaces that share a boundary, and you want to join them into a single surface?

Comment: Not exactly. I have two surfaces that do not share any boundary edge/point. Any i need to know how can i call this object.

Comment: Could it still be a surface, or for surface it is obligatory to have some boundaries between its parts?

Comment: From my perspective, a surface may be an object that has multiple components. So, I could talk about a surface that is two disjoint spheres, for example. However, it is important to clarify your terms. Since some people will assume a surface is connected, you should say that in your work the term encompasses objects that have multiple components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only requirement for a surface is that it be two dimensional. It can be connected or not connected. So it's OK mathematically to call your multi-component terrain object a "surface", even though in everyday language people might think of it as several surfaces.